# Get gradient to work with background color

Tags: css, button, gradient

Right now I have this CSS for a button:

```
background: #19558D url(../images/gradient.gif) repeat-x top left;
```

The gradient appears, but the background color doesn't. When I reload the page, the color appears for a split second, but then disappears to the gradient. How can I get both of them to work?

Comment: I think the order should be: `url(...) repeat-x top left #19558D`

Comment: nah, doesn't make a difference...

Comment: Hmmm you should post a link/example...

Comment: sure... I'm trying to use jsFiddle, but how do I upload my gradient image to it?

Comment: Upload it to something like imageshack and copy-paste the full url to the CSS.

Comment: Ok here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/meltzerj/H62YC/  The gradient isn't work in the fiddle...

Comment: Ok, what are the dimensions of the gradient??

Comment: 20 pixel height, and 1 pixel width: http://www.generateit.net/gradient/index.htm?start_colour=%23FFFFFF&end_colour=%23666666&height=20&width=1&type=top

Comment: I think that your button isn't bigger than 20px height, so the bg isn't shown because your gradient isn't transparent

Comment: ohhh, how do I fix that? I'm new to gradients and graphic design...

Comment: You would have to either make it smaller, or make one of the two colors transparent with something like photoshop (ex. fade from black to transparent, instead of black to grey, and then set a background color that would pretty much replace the transparent.)

Comment: Making it smaller doesn't work, so I think I'll have to make it transparent... I really don't know how to do this though...

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this? Notice how there is a gradient from white to black and then the rest of the page solid black... http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/cACwf/

Comment: I actually figured it out using just image gradients. If you add an answer I'll accept it because you helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have several options:

**1. Use Only Images:**

You can do the job by editing the gradient so that it looks exactly how you like it to be, without any new CSS. (This would be the one you used to solve the problem).

**2. Use Image on the top and the rest in solid color:**

```
element{ background:#000 (url) top left repeat-x; }
```

This will place the image in `url` at the top, and make the rest of the element of a certain solid color. Be aware that if the image covers all of the element and isn't transparent, then the solid color will not be visible.

**3. Make the gradient transparent/alpha:**

*If* the gradient covers all of the element, you can make it transparent, or semi transparent, so that the CSS background-color is visible behind it. For example, if you make a gradient that goes from black to transparent, and then add a white CSS bg, then you will get a black to white gradient. Be aware that the only images that will work with this method are `.png` ones because they are the only ones that support alpha levels (partial transparencies).

Answer (score 0):

is the GIF transparent? I use PNG format as PNG-24 allows alphablending masks, where as GIF only supports transparent or not (1/0)

But I think you need to post a link to it or a image of what it looks like, including the GIF.
We need some pixels specs, such as width and height to fully understand the problem.

Comment: Yup, this is the image I'm using: http://www.generateit.net/gradient/index.htm?start_colour=%23FFFFFF&end_colour=%23666666&height=20&width=1&type=top